# Go Plugin variable initialization

Tags: go, plugins

This is a general question about Go Plugin initialization.

I want to make a certain package in a Go program to a Go Plugin.

The package (say `mypackage`) has a variable which is initialized with a function call from a certain package in the executable. (E.g. a variable of type `interface Logger` which is to be initialized by a `logger.CreateLogger` function.)

In order to make `mypackage` a plugin, I need to create a `main` package, embed `mypackage` inside `main`, and export an api `Init` in package `main` which accepts a function which can get me a logger.

I want to do this so as to reduce the dependencies of my plugin. The `mypackage` plugin should depend on the `interface Logger` rather than Logger's implementation.

Now the problem is the initialization, in the case of executable, the initialization could have happened as below:

```
package mypackage

var dlog = logger.CreateLogger("mypackage")
```

And the logger can be used in any `func init()` function of `mypackage`.

After converting to a plugin, it can't be initialized like this. It has to be initialized at a later point after the `main.Init` is invoked.

The `func init` is invoked when the plugin is Opened, so it cannot be used to initialize variables.

Only solution seems to be a creating a function per package, and invoke it from an exported function in `main` package.

```
package mypackage

var dlog Logger

func Init(f createLoggerType){
   dlog = f()
   yetanotherpackage.Init(f)
}

package main

func Init(f createLoogerType) {
    mypackage.Init(f)
    anotherpackage.Init(f)        
}
```

Is there a better way to initialize? I tried checking `github.com/facebookgo/inject` but couldn't figure out how it can be used in case of plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your solution, but if you want to be able to use it in variable declarations and package `init()` functions, this is how you can do it. I also think it's easier to use the plugin this way, but this requires a common, shared package between your main app and the plugin.

One option would be to create a "store" package, which could store factory functions or pre-created loggers.

Let's say the `Logger` interface definition is in `mylogger`:

```
package mylogger

type Logger interface { Log(string) }
```

The `store` for example:

```
package store

import "mylogger"

var LoggerFactory func(string) mylogger.Logger
```

And in your main app initialize it **before** you load / open the `mypackage` plugin:

```
package main

import "store"

func main() {
    store.LoggerFactory = logger.CreateLogger

    // Now proceed to load / open mypackage plugin
}
```

Then the `mypackage` plugin may look like this:

```
package mypackage

import "store"

var dlog = store.LoggerFactory("mypackage")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 1) the logger is created by a framework, so i cannot create a logger from within the plugin. the logger framework lies in the executable which opens the plugin, 2) my point is to make plugin not contain the logger framework in itself. rather depend on the logger interface which will be initialized when plugin is loaded. plugin just needs to tell which type of logger it wants. and after that plugin works on the interface. 3) `init` cannot be used because it is called before any `plugin.Lookup` can be performed

Comment: @weima See edited answer. Now the plugin does not create loggers, it does not refer to the logger implementation.

Comment: in other words, your solution is: instead of passing the `createLoggerType` to the plugin as an argument to its `InitPlugin` function, create a new package in the executable which holds the same function in an exported variable, and this `package store` has a minimum set of dependencies. This is what i wanted to avoid actually, the plugin importing anything other than the interface and implementation being supplied to the plugin rather than plugin deciding the implementation. and what if i want to decide at runtime the Factory for the Logger, depending on the plugin type.

Comment: This is not so much problem in C/C++, i was expecting same way. in Go, even a very simple plugin, when built copies in itself a large amount of packages. i somehow don't like it.

Comment: @weima There is nothing wrong with your solution, but I thought you wanted to be able to use it in variable declarations and package `init()` functions, and my solution allows you to do so.

Comment: i mean to say that, if i use my solution way, variables cannot be initialized when plugin is opened. it has to be done via spacially written `Init`functions just for this purpose, and for every package. But i will try to use your suggestion. Thanks ! :)

Comment: and lately i am getting fatal errors randomly, raised an issue  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19824